# how to get Razorpay payment method name in local or session variable

Tags: codeigniter, payment, razorpay

Am currently using Razorpay in my wordpress site. In that, I am getting razorpay_payment_id as a response on Successful transcations. but, I couldn't find the payment method(ex: wallet,netbanking) used by the end user!! I want to capture the payment method used by the end user! How to acheive this??

Here is my code to make request and receive response from razorpay,

```
var options={
        "key": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "amount": $('input:radio[name="donate_amnt"]:checked').val()*100, 
        "name": $("#donor_fname").val(),
        "description": "Donation amount",
        "callback_url": 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        "handler": function (response){
            var razorpayid=response.razorpay_payment_id;
                    alert(razorpayid);                              

        },
        "prefill": {
            "contact": $("#donor_mobno").val(),
            "email": $("#donor_emailid").val()
        },
        "theme": {
            "color": "#b80105"`enter code here`
        },
 }
        var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
        rzp1.open();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your callback URL you can get razorpay_order_id, razorpay_payment_id and razorpay_signature(used for verifying. If you used) in post method.

You can make an API call to razorpay using your razorpay credentials and razorpay_payment_id and fetch those payment details. Those payment details have method entity(payment_method) which has payment method like card, UPI ,etc.

Refer [payment API](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/) in Razorpay.

**Edit 1:**

I have noticed that you are using both **callback** and **handler** in options. You should use any one method at a time(check this [link)](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/standard/#step-2-pass-order-id-and-other-options).

If you are using handler function you should send those Razorpay data to your backend and make an API request.